# selecting and Inserting data from two different servers

Tags: mysql, psql

I have two server mysql and psql. I am fetching data from mysql server database table and inserting it into my psql server. The way I am doing is by selecting all the column from mysql server and saving it into an array.

```
sql->prepare("SELECT id, date,studentName, FROM student", array());

variablArray= array();
```

Then inserting the data in psql with the help of implode().

```
psql->prepare("INSERT INTO student",implode(",", $variableArray);
```

The problem is every time I ran the query I too 45 min to complete, because I truncate the psql database table before inserting so that the query can run.

Is there is an another way to do this?

Comment: How many records do you insert? If you have many records (100K or so), you should consider a direct way of transferring the data (mysql -> psql) instead of (mysql -> PHP app -> psql).

Comment: @Alexei - MySQL has no way to talk to a different engine; can psql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the duration is related to data volume, you should consider syncing only the modified data:

- put an `IsDirty` flag on each `student` record
- sync (delete + insert or simple updates) data only for records where IsDirty = 1

This should work decently if a fairly small amount of records change between the sync.

Another option is to try to sync data directly between MySql and PSql as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965241/im-using-postgres-database-i-want-to-create-dblink-with-mysql-database-what-s). Also, take a look upon [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html).